# Connecting to Androidx86 on VirtualBox from IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I currently have Android 4.4 RC1 (http://www.android-x86.org/)  installed on VirtualBox. My host OS is Fedora 20. The VM runs fine, and it is possible to download and execute other apps, send mail etc.

I would like to use this VM as a target device for Android development in IntelliJ 13, just as I would otherwise connect my physical Android device via a USB cable. However, I cannot quite figure out how to configure the VM/IntelliJ in order to make this connection possible. The VM does not show up under either running or connected/USB devices.

What steps do I need to go through to get this working?